# SQL: how to compare corrosponding values two rows from same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have two tables:

```
VendorTrading;
id  date
1   01-01-2015
2   01-01-2015

CustomerProducts;
id tradeID ProductName Quantity
1  1       XYZ         20
2  2       ABC         30
```

I need to make comparison of two product's quantity, of names will be given as parameters, on a particular date.
here is my query so far,

```
Select sum(Cp.ProductQuantity) 
FROM VendorTrading VT inner join CustomerProducts CP on VT.Id = CP.VendorTradingId
WHERE  CP.ProductName = ISNULL ('XYZ', CP.ProductName) and VT.Tradedate = isnull('2015-01-20',VT.Tradedate)
```

which only returns sum of anyone's quantity. How can I achieve that result? I need to put them on a graph in crystal report.
Further more I need to vice versa of same thing but with Two dates but one particular product.

Comment: Could you please give your expected output for us.

Comment: Two rows, each should be total sum of all quantities of its product on a particular date. As product names and date are given as parameters.

Comment: If you want 2 rows returned, use `productname in ('xyz','abc') ... group by productname`.  Also, not sure why you're using `isnull`...

Comment: Wonderful, Would you like to give this is an answer, I'll accept it. It worked. And isnull have a reason. Sorry I should have explain it earlier or I had removed it at all. anyway, Thanks @sgeddes

Comment: No worries.  Just accept the post from @Loser -- change the equals to `in` and it will work the same way.  The key is using `group by` when using aggregates to return multiple results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return sum of anyone's quantity, you should use group by.

```
Select CP.ProductName,sum(Cp.ProductQuantity) 
FROM VendorTrading VT inner join CustomerProducts CP 
ON VT.Id = CP.VendorTradingId
WHERE  CP.ProductName = ISNULL('XYZ', CP.ProductName)
AND VT.Tradedate = isnull('2015-01-20',VT.Tradedate)
AND CP.ProductName in ('xyz','abc')
GROUP BY CP.ProductName
```

Comment: not anyone, I want sum of both Products. of which names will be given as parameter. I want two rows, Two sums of two products

Answer (score 0):

If you want compare more than 2 products, the query must be use group by.
Answer of @Loser is good for your question so far. Maybe you should give us more detail of your expected result.